# How to detect if the user is active only on one device at a given time in both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, swift

I am working on an app, where it requires only one active session for a single user, irrespective of the device he logs in. I have not yet coded for this but I am looking to know if I am heading in the right direction OR is there a better way to handle this

This application will be always connected to the internet so there's no offline mode and hence here's my approach to handle the single session case

1. On calling the login service from DeviceA, the server will maintain a sessionId.
2. If the user does a login from any other device (DeviceB), then the server will check if it's from DeviceA with DeviceA_sessionID? and if not it will send a `400 BadRequest response` to the DeviceB with a message "Please logout from all the device you are logged in to use the app"
3. SessionId on the server can be valid for 2 days or a week.

The main problem I am trying to solve here is that I don't want to have any device oriented dependencies, because the vendorId or any Id can change when we do a factory reset or reinstall the app or purchase a new device.

On step number 2, I am thinking will it be a good idea to just terminate the DeviceA session and allow the login into DeviceB with a new session Id and then show a message on DeviceA that your session has been terminated? Or just wait till the session expires?

With the help of sessionIds on the server, I can make sure that the server has the logic to determine that at a time only one device session per user is active and any other sessions are just terminated.

Also, users change their devices so I assume with sessionId the user can still login and have a new sessionId created for its new device and the server can terminate the old ones.

Let me know if this is a valid approach or is there a better way to handle this case.

Comment: How are you identifying unique devices, since iOS eliminated the unique device identifier?  Some other use cases you didn't mention, what happens if a user's session crashes (ie doesn't exit gracefully).  If they try to re-login from the same device, but a new session is recognized, are they going to have to wait a week?  How is a session ended and cleared?

Comment: I am not coz of the limitations of ios, what i plan to do is when the device makes the request it will check if session id is not expired and if not then process the request. And if the session expires then show the login screen again. I plan to use JWT tokens here @MichaelDougan

Comment: Another thread suggested that after a successful login, the API could return a UUID which would then be saved in the user's keychain.  I'm not familiar with JWT tokens, but perhaps that is similar to how they work?  First time logging in from a device, the device would send up a blank UUID and the API would return one.  Subsequent logins would pass the saved UUID up to the API for validation.

Comment: I did think about that one but then uuid will be there forever and also it does not expire, jwt already has a inbuilt token expiry time and i plan to use that and show login screen if token is expired at my end. @MichaelDougan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I got this resolved was by using `sessions` and not `JWT`. The motivation to not use JWT was we were not implementing/using any claims here to communicate with the server for anything.

Also when you login from a different device we wanted the old tokens to be invalidated and sessions can be invalidated by the server easily whereas the stateless nature of JWT does not allow us to do that and the token will be valid until it is expired.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any kind of authorization and device B is allowed to interrupt device's A session, you can refresh authorization token  every request. So then right after new auth, the previous device's session will expire.

For example you can use JWT Authorization token. More [here](https://jwt.io).

Comment: we do have a login service but we don't have a JWT token being returned for the login, so I guess for this to work we need to setup JWT on the server side?

Comment: @NSDumb yes. But you can use any similar time of auth session tokens.